# Excel column can't be included in sort

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a spreadsheet that I want to sort by Column A.

If I click Column A and hit command-A it will select only that column and therefore will only sort that column.

If I click in Column B and hit command-A it selects all the data in Columns B to W (the extent of the rest of the data) but not Column A. This allows me to sort the rest of the sheet but not by Column A.

If I force the selection of column A and columns B-W then the sort option disables.

I have unhidden all columns and filled all empty cells. There are no formulae in the cells I want to sort.

Why can't I select the whole sheet and why can't I sort by Column A? What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

After poking around (and tearing my hair out) I discovered that the bulk of my sheet (Columns B-W) were defined as a table. This meant that Column A had no real relationship with B-W other than being on the same page.

I solved it by converting Columns B-W back to a data range at which point I could include Column A in the sorts.